# How do we send back the result of processed message by actor to the actual sender

Tags: scala, akka

I created a simple Actor which receives a message from a sender and process that message and that processed result needs to be sent back to the sender .

I tried to achieve that above requirement via Actor model and sender

Actor Code :

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props

class HelloWorld extends Actor {

  var result:Int =0
  def receive = {

    case dataStr:String =>result =process(dataStr)
    sender ! result

  }

  def process(str:String):Int ={

  str.length +30
 }
 }
```

ActorApp Code :

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}

object ActorApp {

  def main(args :Array[String]) ={

    val system = ActorSystem("SimpleActorSystem")
    val actorObj1:ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[HelloWorld],"helloworld1")
    val res =actorObj1 ! "Hi"
    println(res)

   }

 }
```

I got the below output :

```
 ()
 [INFO] [10/08/2016 23:21:50.438] [SimpleActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://SimpleActorSystem/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.Integer] from Actor[akka://SimpleActorSystem/user/helloworld1#-233096668] to Actor[akka://SimpleActorSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I am expecting output as below in the main object(ActorApp) :

```
 32
```

How do I send back the processed output back to sender? Also what does this INFO log say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what you're doing: You're sending a message to your `HelloWorld` actor, receive and process it there and then send a message from this actor to the actor who sent the original message (remember: `sender` returns an `ActorRef`).

But: What actor is that? There is only the one `HelloWorld` actor. So naturally `sender` isn't defined (since you didn't actually send the message from another actor). If you send messages to receivers which can't be delivered they go to akkas dead-letters system actor (`Actor[akka://SimpleActorSystem/deadLetters]`) - and that's what the log message says.

So how do you actually return a result? You use the *ask-pattern*.

import `akka.pattern.ask` and use a question mark instead of the exclamation mark to do so. Now you'll end up with a future which will (hopefully) be resolved with your result:

```
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val system = ActorSystem("SimpleActorSystem")
val actorObj1:ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[HelloWorld],"helloworld1")
val resFuture = (actorObj1 ? "Hi").mapTo[Int]
val res = Await.result(resFuture, 5 seconds)
println(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation,  So,when do we need to use sender? Is sender for sending messages to another different Actor?

Comment: No, `sender` is the message sender. Whenever you send messages into an actor system via `?`, akka is nice enough to keep track of it, so the next message sent back via `sender !` is used to resolve the `Future`.